# Trying to Scrape a tree list with Python's Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to extract a list of data from a website using Python and BeautifulSoup. I came across a website, and I need to extract a list of data from it. I have attached a screenshot of what I want to extract.

I would be grateful if someone could guide me on how to write Python code using BeautifulSoup to extract this data from the website.

Url : https://ec.europa.eu/tools/eudamed/#/screen/nomenclatures

Thank you in advance for your help.

Please help i tried some codes but did not worked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH0Ov.png)

Comment: Please upload your code, as text not an image, showing us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the page is dynamically loaded via JavaScript, so you can't extract the data by parsing a static downloaded copy of the html.
Instead of focussing on the DOM, you should take a look at the "Network" tab. There you can see that every time you open something in the tree view data is accessed from "https://ec.europa.eu/tools/eudamed/api/devices/nomenclatures/root/children". This is the data you are looking for, and it's already in json format.